# Binary Tree Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree, coredump

```
struct Tree{
    char string[30];
    int hmanyt;
    struct Tree * left;
    struct Tree * right;
};
typedef struct Tree * drzewo;
void printftree(drzewo* korzen)
{
    if((*korzen)->left != NULL)
        printftree(&((*korzen)->left));
    printf("%s(%d)\n",(*korzen)->string,(*korzen)->hmanyt);
    if(strcmp((*korzen)->string,"boril\0")==0)
        (((*korzen)->right)->left)->left=NULL;
    if((*korzen)->right != NULL)
        printftree(&((*korzen)->right));
    return ;
}
void erease(drzewo* korzen)
{
    if((*korzen)->left==NULL && (*korzen)->right==NULL)
    {
        *korzen=NULL;
        free (*korzen);
        return ;
    }
    else
    {
        if((*korzen)->left !=NULL)
        {
            erease(&((*korzen)->left));
            (*korzen)->left=NULL;
            free((*korzen)->left);
        }
        if((*korzen)->right !=NULL)
        {
            erease(&((*korzen)->right));
            (*korzen)->right=NULL;
            free((*korzen)->right);
        }
    }
    *korzen=NULL;
    free(*korzen);
    return ;
}
void add(drzewo* korzen,char word[])
{
    while(*korzen!=NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp((*korzen)->string,word)==0)   {
            ((*korzen)->hmanyt)++;
            return; }
        else if(strcmp((*korzen)->string,word)<0)   {
            korzen=&((*korzen)->right); }
        else if(strcmp((*korzen)->string,word)>0)   {
            korzen=&((*korzen)->left);
                }
    }
    *korzen=(drzewo) malloc(sizeof(drzewo));
    strcpy(((*korzen)->string),word);
    printf("%p",(*korzen)->left);
    printf("%p\n",(*korzen)->right);
    (*korzen)->hmanyt=1;    
    return;
}
int main()
{
    drzewo korzen =NULL;
    char *words[10]={"alfabet","borixon","aaaaaa","zombie","bobas","kamil","agnieszka","kokos","zamach"};
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        add(&korzen,words[i]);
    printf("test1\n");
    printftree(&korzen);
    printf("test");
    erease(&korzen);
    return 0;
}
```

So this is my implementation of binary tree. Which loads 10 words to the tree . Sadly during 'printing' this tree I came across a problem which is core dumped.  I don't know why but one of the structurs "has" (*korzen)->left that isn't NULL, my funcion wants to acess it,and the core dumped appears. After adding two lines

```
if(strcmp((*korzen)->string,"boril\0")==0)
    (((*korzen)->right)->left)->left=NULL;
```

it works fine, but I don't know why i have this issue. Another issue is that despite  having such a line as:

```
(*korzen)->hmanyt=1;
```

Afterall it doesn't have this value ... (only first word has hmanyt==1) . Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Regarding your problem, have you tried running in a debugger to catch the crash in action? That will tell you *where* it happens and also let you examine the function call stack and the values of variables.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you don't need to explicitly add a string terminator in string literals, those are added automatically by the compiler.

Comment: I didn't use debugger (frankly i don't know how to use it properly.) But I know where the smthing weird is happening.

Comment: some separation of code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) by a blank line will greatly help with the readability/understandability of the posted code

Comment: these two lines: `printf("%p",(*korzen)->left);
    printf("%p\n",(*korzen)->right);` are using the wrong kind of variable parameters.  suggest: `printf("%p",(void*)(*korzen)->left);
    printf("%p\n", (void*)(*korzen)->right);

Comment: when calling `malloc()`, 1)  do not cast the returned value.  The returned value has type `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  2)  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: in the function: `erease()` these two lines need to be swapped. `        *korzen=NULL; free (*korzen);`  and  `(*korzen)->left=NULL free((*korzen)->left);`  and : `(*korzen)->right=NULL; free((*korzen)->right);` and `*korzen=NULL; free(*korzen);` because the actual pointer is being set to NULL before being passed to `free()`, so the actual memory allocation is 1) not being released 2) the result is massive memory leaks.

Comment: This code: ` *korzen = malloc(sizeof(drzewo));
    strcpy(((*korzen)->string),word);
    printf("%p", (void*)(*korzen)->left);
    printf("%p\n", (void*)(*korzen)->right);
    (*korzen)->hmanyt=1;` which is supposed to be initializing the struct that it malloc's fails to set the two pointers `left` and `right` to NULL.   This is a major problem in the posted code

Comment: this line: `char *words[10]={"alfabet","borixon","aaaaaa","zombie","bobas","kamil","agnieszka","kokos","zamach"};` results in an unitialized pointer in the `words[]` array.  suggest: char *words[]={"alfabet","borixon","aaaaaa","zombie","bobas","kamil","agnieszka","kokos","zamach"};`  which, amongst other things, lets the compiler figure out the number of entries in the array.

Comment: This line: `for(int i=0;i<9;i++)` has a 'magic' number 9.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest: `for( size_t i=0; i<;(sizeof(words)/sizeof(words[0]); i++ )`  which, amongst other things lets the compiler calculate the limit value.  Note: `sizeof` returns a `size_t` so to avoid a compiler warning, declare `i` as a `size_t` rather than a `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bad idea to assign `NULL` to a pointer which you want to `free`. Change place of `*korzen=NULL;` and `free(*korzen);` in your function `erease`:

Adapt your function `erease` like this:

```
void erease(drzewo* korzen)
{
    if ( *korzen == NULL )
        return;

    if( (*korzen)->left !=NULL )
    {
        erease(&((*korzen)->left)); // (*korzen)->left is freed in erease
    }
    if( (*korzen)->right !=NULL )
    {
        erease(&((*korzen)->right)); // (*korzen)->right is freed in erease
    }
    free(*korzen);
    *korzen=NULL;
    return;
}
```

If you insert a new node in your tree you have to initialize its childs `(*korzen)->left` and `(*korzen)->right` with `NULL`. Further the type of `drzewo` is `struct Tree*`, so `sizeof(drzewo)` gives the size of a pointer not the size of `struct Tree`.

```
void add(drzewo* korzen,char word[])
{
    while( *korzen != NULL )
    {
        int cmp = strcmp( ( *korzen )->string, word );
        if ( cmp == 0 )
        {
            ((*korzen)->hmanyt)++;
            return;
        }
        else if( cmp<0 ) {
            korzen=&((*korzen)->right);
        }
        else if (cmp>0 ) {
            korzen=&((*korzen)->left);
        }
    }
    // allocate new node and initiialize
    *korzen=malloc(sizeof(struct Tree)); // allocat sizeof struct Tree ( not sizeof pointer to Tree) 
    ( *korzen )->left = NULL;  // <- left child is null
    ( *korzen )->right = NULL; // <- right child is null
    strcpy(((*korzen)->string),word);
    (*korzen)->hmanyt=1;    
    return;
}
```

Finally your function `printftree`:

```
void printftree(drzewo* korzen)
{
    if ( *korzen == NULL )
        return;
    if( (*korzen)->left != NULL)
        printftree(&((*korzen)->left));
    printf("%s(%d)\n",(*korzen)->string,(*korzen)->hmanyt);
    if((*korzen)->right != NULL)
        printftree(&((*korzen)->right));
    return ;
}
```

Comment: Things that u pointed out are really on point (:))!! Thank you for that . Sadly it doesn't help me with the core dumped :/ .

Comment: Really really thank you !! Not only u gave me solution but showed me few otehr things that i should improve. But can u expain me why this change is necessary ? I have one more question ,but i dont want to spam this thread (not entirely linked to my issue) is it okay to pw you ?

Comment: ok nvm,(i thought that i can private messeage you) .After loading whole book and transfering it to the binary tree I will have to print in file x words that appears in the book the most ( if some words appears the same number of times it will have to be sorted from a to z) . I dont know how to do it at all. And you looks like a person that used to compile few trees in ur life :) , that's why i wanted some advices.

Comment: I'm really desperate and I think u will be able to help me. So I ended my program, or I just thought I did. Sometimes work but ussually it's core dumped issue. I wanted to check where the issue is , so i made a line with printf to find wheter it will be printed or not. Based on it the issue is first 20 lines of int main ... This is it: <http://pastebin.com/95Lg4pGC> Sorry for the polish language in it. I can translate it if You need it to help me.